# Confused about grep and the * wildcard

Tags: command-line, grep, find

I am running the following command in order to find all files/directories that do not have anything to do with "flash_drive_data":

```
find . -not -path './flash_drive_data*' | grep "./*flash*"
```

There are a few things which I tried that are confusing me:

1. When I run the above command, I get a few "partial" hits (i.e they do not completely match the `*flash*` pattern. For example:

```
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/cli.pyi
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/signals.pyi
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/templating.pyi
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/sessions.pyi
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/json
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/json/tag.pyi
```

The `3/flas` at the end is being highlighted.

2. When I replaced `grep "*flash*"` with just `grep "*"`, I expected to get all files returned by find, but I got none. Why? Then, when I did `grep "**"` I believe I got all the files (or at least I think I did). Again, why is that?

3. Finally, the objective of what I was doing above was to make sure that when I ran `find . -not -path './flash_drive_data*'` I was getting nothing related to flash_drive_data. It seemed like I did (with some unexpected behavior with grep as I explained above). However, when I ran:
`find . -not -path './flash_drive_data*' -exec tar cfv home.tar.bz '{}' +`

I was getting output including things like:

```
./flash_drive_data/index2/ask-sdk-core/dist/dispatcher/error/handler/
```

so flash_drive_data files were being included.

Comment: `*` is not a wildcard in grep - it's a [regular expression quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

Comment: I bet the `k` in `3/flask` is **not** highlighted.

Comment: @pLumo my bad you're right

Comment: Are you really saying that `echo ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/flask/cli.pyi | grep "*flash*"` gives output on your machine? That should return nothing since `*flash*` is invalid (the first `*` isn't quantifying anything). Are you _sure_ that `grep "*flash*"` was returning the output you show? Were you perhaps using `grep ".flash*` instead?

Comment: @terdon sorry you're right it was ./*flash*

Comment: Check [re_format(7)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format), especially the section “BASIC REGULAR EXPRESSIONS” starting from “**The following is a list of basic regular expressions:**”, which are used in [grep(1)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man1/grep). These differ from shell [glob(7)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man7/glob)s, which is what [find(1)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man1/find) uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -not -path './flash_drive_data*' | grep "./*flash*"
```

The thing here is that `grep` uses regular expressions, while `find -path` uses shell glob style pattern matches. The asterisk has a different meaning in those two.

The regular expression `./*flash*` matches first any character (`.`), then zero or more slashes (`/*`), then a literal string `flas`, then any number (zero or more) of `h` characters. `3/flas` matches that (with zero times `h`), and so would e.g. `reflash` (with zero times `/`).

You could just use `grep flash` instead, given that it matches anywhere in the input, so leading and tailing "match anything" parts are unnecessary.

Or use `find -path './*flash*' -and -not -path './flash_drive_data*'`

> When I replaced `grep "*flash*"` with just `grep "*"`, I got [no matches].

Since the asterisk means "any number of the previous atom", it's not really well defined here. `grep` interprets that as a literal asterisk, but really it should be an error.

> However, when I ran: `find . -not -path './flash_drive_data*' -exec tar cfv home.tar.bz '{}' +` I was getting output including things like:
>
> `./flash_drive_data/index2/ask-sdk-core/dist/dispatcher/error/handler/`
>
> so `flash_drive_data` files were being included.

Note that `tar` stores files recursively, and the first output of that `find` is `.` for the current directory, so everything will be stored. You may want to use `! -type d` with `find` to exclude directories from the output, or (better), look at the `-exclude=PATTERN` options to `tar`.

Answer (score 15):

You're confusing the different meaning of `*` for [Shell Filename Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08) and [Posix Basic Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

In Regex, `*` is the quantifier for the character in front of it, so `h*` means 0 or more occurrences of `h`. If you want "any number of any character", use `.*`.

`grep '*'` would look for literal `*` as there is nothing in front of it to quantify, while `grep '**'` would like for 0 or more occurrences of `*`, so everything will fit as 0 occurrences of something will always fit.

---

**Anyways**, you should rather use `find` with argument `-path "*/flash/*"` instead of `grep` the output of `find`.