# grep regular expression to remove packages

Tags: grep, regex, wildcards

This is an unexpected result I get

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-*
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-26-generic                   5.4.0-26.30+2                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-26
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-28-generic                   5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-28
...
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-*
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic                        5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic                        5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
...
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-5.4.0-*
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic                              5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-28-generic                              5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
...
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image-5.4.0-*
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic                                5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic                                5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
...
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-*-5.4.0-*
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-*-5.4*
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-*-5\.4*
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-*-5\\.4*
$ dpkg -l | grep "linux-*-5\.4*"
$ dpkg -l | grep "linux-*-5\\.4*"
$ dpkg -l | grep 'linux-*-5\\.4*'
```

As soon as I add `*` prior to `.`, `grep` stops matching.
I would like to match any of the 4 cases (`modules`, etc.)

**What is the correct regex so I can still match the results?**

Among these, I would like to further filter `*5.4.0-[2,3]*`.
But this is what I see as part of the output to `$ dpkg -l | grep 5.4.0-[2,3]*`

[image]

**Why would lines with `*5.4.0-4*` match? The colorized part is what matches, which is `5.4.0-` in this case, and I do not see how that matches the regex `5.4.0-[2,3]*`.**
(I managed to remove those matches with `$ dpkg -l | grep 5.4.0-[2,3][[:digit:]]*`, but still I would like to understand why the unexpected matches here).

Or,

**How can I combine matching wildcards, text, and multiple strings?**
e.g., something like `linux-` plus any of `modules`, `image`, `modules-extra`, `modules-nvidia-440`, plus `-5.4.0-`, plus `[2,3]`, plus digit, plus `*`.

Note that this is not an XY problem.
The *motivation* is that I want to use regex to quickly filter a set of package names to remove them all at once.
But in this specific question I am asking why the usage of `grep` I tried did not work and what is the correct way of using it.

Comment: quote your regex, otherwise `bash` will try to match files in your current working dir. And then `[2,3]*` matches `2`, `,` or `3`, any number of times (including not at all), you may want `[23].*` or simply `[23]` if you don't care about the rest.

Comment: You're badly mixing up regular expressions and wildcards. `-*` as a regular expression means any number of (or no) `-`s, not `-` followed by anything as is the case with wildcards.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/714503/regular-expressions-vs-filename-globbing, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167297/confused-about-grep-and-the-wildcard, https://askubuntu.com/questions/681637/grep-the-asterisk-doesnt-always-work, etc.

Comment: @muru - Yes, I was mixing up wildcards with regex.
I think I was not confused about filename globbing, as I am not globbing but only grepping, I guess.